# Un árbol de expresión no puede contener una expresión dinámica

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo un proyecto MVC 5 de ASP

mi modelo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace _2_Hello.Models
{
    public class ItineraryItem
    {
        public DateTime? When { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? Duration { get; set; }
    }
}
```

mi controller

```
using _2_Hello.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace _2_Hello.Controllers
{
    public class ItineraryController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Itinerary
        public ActionResult Create()
        { var model = new ItineraryItem();
            return View(model); }
    }
}
 y mi vista



   @Model 2-Hello.Models.ItineraryItem
    <h2> Create</h2> 
        <div class="editor"> 
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        { 
            <p> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description) 
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description) 
            </p> 
            <p> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.When)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.When) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.When) 
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Duration)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Duration) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Duration)
            </p> 
            <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p> } 
        </div>
```

me marca error en las expresiones lambda `m.Description,` indicandome
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión

```
Error   CS1963  Un árbol de expresión no puede contener una operación dinámica  2-Hello C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\practicando\MVC Succinctly\2-Hello\Views\Itinerary\Create.cshtml 6   Activa
```

cómo lo soluciono? Aclaro que probé poniendo @model pero me indica el error

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado de supresión
Error   CS1031  Se esperaba un tipo 2-Hello C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\practicando\MVC Succinctly\2-Hello\Views\Itinerary\Create.cshtml 1   Activa
```

en la palabra Hello y me dice que Html no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: Hola! esta bien eso de `2-Hello`? no es `_2_Hello`.

Comment: si, esta bien, lo que me decís es válido para el using

Comment: Deberia ser `@model _2_Hello.Models.ItineraryItem`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un dificil y a la vez sencillo error, solo debes cambiar tu `@Model` por `@model`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Explicacion

> **¿Qué significa el error?**
>
> Pues bien como su nombre lo dice **Un árbol de expresión no puede contener una expresión dinámica**, que significa que cuando construimos una **Expression<>** que mas que darnos un valor nos describe la forma de acceder a un valor o realizar una operacion (una expresion puede contener operandos, operaciones,etc) y en el caso de construir una expresion no podemos usar como base un objeto **dynamic**, necesitamos un tipo concreto. Y si vemos los metodos como LabelFor, TextBoxFor, etc veremos que usan una expresion.

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
  return LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(html, expression, (string) null);
}
```

pero...

> **¿Porque mi modelo es dynamic?**
>
> Cuando usamos `@Model` (con mayuscula) le decimos al motor de razor que quremos acceder al objeto que es el modelo de la vista, mientras que cuando usamos `@model` le decimos a nuestra vista la clase de modelo que tendra asignado. Y en el caso de que no definamos que clase tendra por modelo nuestra vista esta emplea el tipo **dynamic** por flexibilidad.

Comment: usando model me dice que Hello2 y html no existen en el contexto actual

Comment: Deberia ser @model _2_Hello.Models.ItineraryItem

Comment: me sirvió, muchas gracias