# Error "Un arbol de expresion no puede contener una operacion dinamica" En un Proyecto Con MVC en ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un proyecto en ASP.NET MVC tengo el siguiente error:

> *"Un árbol de expresión no puede contener una operación dinámica"*

Qué puede ser?

Comment: Tenes public la clase Contacto?

Comment: hola, si está en public

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Un árbol de expresión no puede contener una expresión dinámica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64023/un-%c3%a1rbol-de-expresi%c3%b3n-no-puede-contener-una-expresi%c3%b3n-din%c3%a1mica)

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la sintaxis que tienes `@model` con M mayuscula.

```
@model FormularioProIII.Models.Contacto
```